# Is it possible to make a C++ class be the delegate of Objc class?

Tags: c++, objective-c

Because I need to inherit some handler declared in C++ as superclasses, I have to declare my class as a `C++` class. But also I want to make it be the **delegate** of two `Objective-C` classes. It is unavoidable to use delegate pattern in my C++ class, but I don't know how to make a C++ class to be the delegate of Objective-C class.

Is it possible? Or is there an indirect way to do it?

Comment: To make a C++ class to be the delegate of Objective-C class, you need to create a bridge object (Objective-C class), which is delegate of Objective-C objects and call C++ methods when delegate's methods is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty example.

Interface and implementation of the Objective-C class that needs to delegate to C++:

```
@interface MyClassOC : NSObject
@property id<MyDelegateProtocol> myDelegate;
-(void)doStuff;
@end

@implementation MyClassOC
-(void)doStuff {
    if (self.myDelegate) {
        [self.myDelegate performOperation];
    }
}
@end
```

The `MyDelegateProtocol` is

```
@protocol MyDelegateProtocol
-(void)performOperation;
@end
```

The C++ class to be used as a delegate:

```
class MyDelegateCPP {
public:
    void performOperation();
};

void MyDelegateCPP::performOperation() {
    cout << "C++ delegate at work!\n";
}
```

`MyClassOC` cannot use `MyDelegateCPP` directly, so we need to wrap the C++ class in something that can use C++ and can be used by the Objective-C class. Objective-C++ to the rescue!

The wrapper class:

```
@interface MyDelegateOCPP : NSObject <MyDelegateProtocol>
-(void)performOperation;
@end

// This needs to be in a .mm (Objective-C++) file; create a normal 
// Objective-C file (.m) and change its extension to .mm, which will 
// allow you to use C++ code in it.
@implementation MyDelegateOCPP {
    MyDelegateCPP * delegateCPP;
}
-(id)init {
    delegateCPP = new MyDelegateCPP();
    return self;
}
-(void)performOperation {
    delegateCPP->performOperation();
}
@end
```

This could be used as follows:

```
MyDelegateOCPP * delegate = [[MyDelegateOCPP alloc] init];
MyClassOC * classOC = [[MyClassOC alloc] init];
classOC.myDelegate = delegate;
[classOC doStuff];
```

Again, this is just an oversimplified sketch, but hopefully it gives you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know delegate is return data in Objective-C.So you create class as super class use C++ language,it will return data.So Let's do it.
First,You use C++ language that mean creat C++ class,and then add objective-c class.So C++ class and objc class is mixing in one xxx.h/xxx.mm.

Second,you also need delegate,you only use objc class implement in other objc class.

See it test code.

```
TestViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
class testC
{
   public:
   static int useCMethod();
};

@protocol helloCDelegate<NSObject>
@optional
- (void)testDelegateTransformDataInTest:(int)testNum;
@end
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<helloCDelegate> delegate;
@end

TestViewController.mm -- section operate implement code

int testC::useCMethod(){
return 3;
}

// you can use C++ method and C++ object in sample method.
// also it use delegate in here,so you can implement in other view controller.
- (void)tapBackTranformReturnData
{
   int num = testC::useCMethod();
   [self.delegate testDelegateTransformDataInTest:num];
 }
```

Oh,one of most important things is that you must change `xxx.m` file to `xxx.mm`.It means Objective-C++ that can use C++ language and Objective-C.

Is this function you need? I hope to help you.